# DB Service accounts: is it possible to avoid storing a password somewhere

Tags: password-management, databases

Is it possible to avoid having to store DB passwords applications/service accounts needing access to the DB? I would like to avoid the risk of a system admin obtaining the password and then accessing the DB himself.

Comment: Of course an Application Firewall to some extend could control access to the DB but this is rather a password protection question.

Comment: What kind of privileges does the admin have on the machine?

Comment: The admin could potentially have full access to the machine. It is this reason that I'm researching how to avoid having DB passwords accessible by him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Integrated Security allows you to use the account already running the application to login to the database thus avoiding the need to put a password in the connection string inside the configuration file

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa984236(v=vs.94)